# Ansible cloudformation vs cloudformation

Tags: ansible, infrastructure-as-code, aws-cloudformation

I would like to know the difference between 
- AWS cloudformation 
- Make AWS cloudformation template through Ansible (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudformation_module.html)

I dont know why would i use Ansible if i already have AWs cloudformation

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to use Ansible for AWS cloudformation if you are fine with just using AWS cloudformation.

Ansible integrated AWS cloudformation so that you can convert your local Ansible files into an AWS cloudformation easily.

I'd suggest using Ansible since it provides a great way to test your stacks locally and then you would make the conversion to AWS cloudformation when ready. This is usage dependent however.